# With delphi, i have a dbgrid. I want when user has filled the row and posted it, the line of grid is readonly

Tags: delphi, row, line, readonly, dbgrid

With delphi, i have a dbgrid. I want  when user has filled the row and posted it, the line of grid is readonly

Do you have any suggestion ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Long time since last Delphi dev but I would have aborted an OnBeforeEdit event if there is data in the buffer.
My two cents

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to keep a list with all rows (All data or just the primary key or the row ID) already updated by the user. Before allowing an update, you check the list.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent accidental / unwanted edits you can turn off the `AutoEdit` property of the TDataSource providing data to the DBGrid. Then be sure any controls like a DBNavigator do not have edit enabled.

From the Delphi Help:

> **Description**
>
> Specifies whether the data source should call the Edit method automatically.
>
> AutoEdit is true by default. If AutoEdit is true, then when a user attempts to modify the data displayed by the control, the data source calls the underlying dataset's Edit method.
>
> Set AutoEdit to false to protect data from unintentional modification. Even if AutoEdit is false, an application can explicitly call a dataset's Edit method to allow data modification.